# What is the estimate price for small ion thrusters on cubesats?

Tags: cubesat, ion-thruster

I can't find much about price for ion thruster and I read from somewhere that most ion thruster are off the rack product. I just need the rough estimate price for a small ion thruster and the closest I found is here (https://www.cubesatshop.com/product/ifm-nano-thruster/) which cost around 30,000 euros. However I am more interested in the BIT-3 & BIT-1 thrusters from Burek (http://www.busek.com/technologies__ion.htm) but they did not mention anything about prices here.

Comment: Your question is clear, concise, and well-sourced, but I think it is probably off-topic. For low volume stuff a company will often negotiate a different price for each customer, whether or not they have an advertised price. I think you have to ask them for a quotation.

Comment: looks like https://www.enpulsion.com/order/ 's offerings range from $50 to $100k